# Are Marwick and Sam a gay couple?

Tags: fantasy-genre, angie-sage, septimus-heap-universe

Sam live alone with Marwick isolated on an island. Suddenly they disappear and are traveling together. The book series is for younger kids, and I don't think Angie Sage would write a direct gay scene in it; but could it be that she imagined both as a gay couple?

Book: TodHunter Moon (follow up in the Septismus Heap universe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the author has confirmed on multiple occasions that [these characters are gay](http://septimusheapblog.com/ask-angie-6/), and by extension that they're a couple. The implication is that while this isn't *especially* controversial in the Septimus Heap universe, they simply haven't told anyone (explaining the lack of in-universe references).

> **Q.** *When I was searching your books earlier I read that Sam Heap and Wolf Boy are gay. Is that true?*
>
> **Angie Sage:** *Yes, it is. We will meet them again in THM book 2. (not sure of the title yet).*

and

> **Angie Sage:**  *Yes, I reckon Sam and Wolf Boy are gay. I don’t think they’ve told anyone yet and no one is going to make a big thing
>   about it. It’s all just kind of normal in Sep world.*

and

> **Angie Sage:** *I didn’t make Sam and Wolf boy gay, they just are. It’s the way they
>   seem together and it’s no big deal. They are still Sam and Wolf Boy.
>   It’s the same with all my characters, I don’t dictate to them, they
>   tell me who they are, not the other way around.*